# How to display ng model value to another page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html page with angular in which ng model returns a address and I want to display the same address in other html page. How to do it? And my code is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Item" placeholder="Enter the IP Address"/>
```

Comment: Are you using ui-router or another router to move between pages? If so, you need to pass the model off into the resolve of the 'next' page.

Comment: to be frank I don't know how to use ng route @rrd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do similarly like this:

```js
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {

     $rootScope.$on('eventName', function(event, args) {
      $scope.emitMessage = args;
        });
    })
    .controller('myCtrl2', function($scope,$rootScope) {
        $scope.onclick = function() {
         $rootScope.$emit('eventName',{msg: 'my message'});
        };
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <p>Message Emitted: {{emitMessage.msg}}</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl2" 
        <button ng-click="onclick()"> click me to emit message</button>
    </div>
    </div>
```